# SQL SSMS IF THEN with multiple criteria across same field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to pull a transaction record from a table if it is type 'C' and has a record post time greater than or equal to the post time for a record with type 'W' where the account numbers and post date are the same. I am struggling with creating an if/then where the posttime for type 'C' >= posttime for type 'W'... any help would be appreciated. I've done these types before but never for the same field where only one record item is different.

Comment: Could you try adding some code/sql query that you've tried to add some context?

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would be most helpful

Comment: Your first problem is you have relational data and most of what you have just described belongs in the ON and WHERE `predicate` clauses.

Comment: Thanks Clifton_h. I will try to work something up with ON and WHERE and see where that gets me. I don't know why I'm having such a hard time with this one - the table is huge so it takes forever to see if what I'm pulling is working or not and I think it's making me overthink it.

Comment: USE TOP 1000 (or some other sample number). Your queries will not take as long.

Also, your answer (which should be in the question still), has me puzzled on one aspect: Do you have two columns `POSTTIME`, `POSTRECORD`? You describe `a record post time greater than or equal` at the same time that you say `post date are the same`.

Comment: I have a field name postdate and a separate field for posttime. I originally tried to solve this by grabbing the next record for each account and postdate but the way the data works another event record will "interrupt" the same transaction (across multiple records) so I was getting very inconsistent results. The only thing I can see to grab related records for each event is to grab those with similar posttimes.

Comment: You are on the right track. Map out the carnality of your problem, and notice what combinations of columns return a unique set of records. That will be in your ON predicate.Then, use Search ARGuments to whittle the results set to only return records that you want to see.

If you have the ON predicate correctly, the INNER JOIN will return unique sets of results.

Comment: @clifton_h There's no need to mark your question as solved.  If an answer solved your problem then accept that answer - it will be shown as having an accepted answer in the list.

Comment: @D Stanley, ummm...this is not my question. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you describe can be accomplished through `JOINS`.
Think `relational data sets` and `SARGs`.

While you still have not given us a table structure (which helps enormously), the solution can help steer you in the right direction. The following assumes a `FACT` table of `TRANSACTIONS`, where the `carnality` to itself is M:M

```
SELECT TOP 1000 A.ACTIONCODE, A.TRAN_RECORD --, any other needed columns
FROM TRANSACTIONS A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ACTIONCODE, POSTTIME, ACCOUNT_NUM, POSTDATE
                FROM   TRANSACTIONS
                WHERE  ACTIONCODE = 'W') B ON A.ACCOUNT_NUM = B.ACCOUNT_NUM
                                          AND A.POSTDATE = B.POSTDATE
WHERE A.ACTIONCODE = 'C'
  AND A.POSTTIME >= B.POSTTIME
```

UPDATED: I accidently forgot to include the correct number of columns. Always specify the same columns (or * if you do not care) that you will be using in your INNER JOIN.

Regardless, we optimize the query by only returning results that we will be using or seeing in our query.

Comment: Thanks Clifton_h, that worked perfectly. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sweet. Mark the answer as solved, please and thank you. :)

Comment: You'll end up with duplications if you can have more than one W in a day.

Comment: @shawnt00 Actually, no. Join is on Account num + Postdate with PostTime as the variable. So unless Time is measured in days, a unique set should return.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the typical method using `exists`:

```
select * from transactions t
where t.actioncode = 'C' and exists (
    select 1 from transactions t2
    where   t2.account_num = t.account_num and t2.postdate = t1.postdate
        and t2.actioncode = 'W'
        and t2.posttime < t1.posttime
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had originally, but it just churned in SSMS without results. Essentially, I just need all 'C' type records returned where there is a 'W' type record with a posttime less than the 'C', but where the account numbers and postdate for the record are the same. posttime, postdate, type, and number are all fields in my table.

SELECT *

FROM TRANSACTIONS

WHERE ACTIONCODE = 'C' AND POSTTIME >=  POSTTIME AND ACTIONCODE = 'W'

Comment: Your query may not be able to use the most efficient index since you reference the same column to itself (in other words, an Index/Table scan is likely).

Also, this was supposed to go with the question. xD

Comment: That should have returned immediately. There's no way for a single row to have multiple values in a column.